# How to Submit data to Azure Sql database from form in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-sql-database

I am having a database created on Azure SQL database and having enough access rights.I want to submit a form data from "SharePoint Online" to Azure SQL database table.

I searched over internet to find out the solution but not found any particular solution.

Looking for approach how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options,

1. Create a Provider hosted addin, create a form to capture the details and you can use C# code behind to connect SQL azure and add data to the table
2. Create a html form (use it directly in Content editor/Script editor or SharePoint hosted addin) to capture the details, and have intermediate web service in Azure which can add data to the table. The html form can invoke this web service through AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please brief me about intermediate service in Azure.

Comment: Its just web service which can do CRUD operations on your SQL azure database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a web API which will accept data as parameters and store it in azure SQL database table.
2. Host that web API in Azure services.
3. From SharePoint online form, on submit button, you can make ajax REST call to azure web service we created with parameters to store in azure database.

Hope this will help!!!